# Cannot remove a cookie - Firefox rejecting cookies from the past

Tags: firefox, cookies, setcookie

I'm losing my mind here - I'm looking into an issue where some signout functionality in an application I have isn't working because the authentication cookie is not being cleared. The thing is that our "signout" endpoint does include the appropriate `set-cookie` header in the response - here's what I get looking at the raw response in Firefox:

```
set-cookie: Auth.myapp=; domain=app.mydomain.com; expires=Thu, 26-Nov-2020 13:19:20 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

Firefox is reporting this error in the console:

> Cookie “Auth.myapp” has been rejected because it is already expired

This is kind of confusing, not only have I successfully used `set-cookie` with a past-date in `expires` before, it's even codified in [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) as the accepted way to request a client remove a cookie:

> Finally, to remove a cookie, the server returns a Set-Cookie header
> with an expiration date in the past.  The server will be successful
> in removing the cookie only if the Path and the Domain attribute in
> the Set-Cookie header match the values used when the cookie was
> created.

So I need to set an `expires` date in the past to clear the cookie ... but doing so causes the browser to reject it? Does anyone know what's going on here?

To be clear I have checked that the cookie name, path, `secure` and `SameSite` match (update: I suspected that because I hadn't explicitly specified a SameSite this might be the cause, but after making sure the cookie is both set and cleared with `SameSite=None` it is still not working).

Comment: By any chance are different subdomains involved here (such as one request made without, and one with)?

Comment: Nah good suggestion but this is all on the same subdomain

Answer (score 11):

As far as I can tell, the message is harmless - the cookies are indeed deleted based on my testing. And Googling the message leads to [this changeset](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/72e7c3e8393ec48d0b8425e6ee64d39b0000f577#l4.97), which indicates that the deletion does happen, just with additional logging.

```cpp
       // If the new cookie has expired -- i.e. the intent was simply to delete
       // the old cookie -- then we're done.
       if (aCookie->Expiry() <= currentTime) {
         COOKIE_LOGFAILURE(SET_COOKIE, aHostURI, aCookieHeader,
                           "previously stored cookie was deleted");
+        CookieLogging::LogMessageToConsole(
+            aCRC, aHostURI, nsIScriptError::warningFlag,
+            CONSOLE_REJECTION_CATEGORY, "CookieRejectedExpired"_ns,
+            AutoTArray<nsString, 1>{
+                NS_ConvertUTF8toUTF16(aCookie->Name()),
+            });
         NotifyChanged(oldCookie, u"deleted", oldCookieIsSession);
         return;
```

The message seems unnecessary however, and there is [a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1676651) about it. The bug report was recently updated to note that this is fixed in [Firefox 114](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/f6e3407883b4).

Comment: Well spotted, so this error may not be related to the issue I am seeing. Hmm

Comment: In my case the cookie wasn't deleted because Webpack dev server was fiddling with it. Firefox gave a confusing error message but it _does_ follow the spec.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs when using a null , false, or empty string in  the cookie value.
It is only flagged as a warning in Firefox.
Other browsers do not show this warning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem today with the same error message as the OP.

This happened in the past and my solution then was, rather than setting a time in the past, I set the value to nothing (as a failsafe) and also set 'expires' to `'time() + 1'` (so a future time with the cookie expiring almost instantly).

```
    setcookie('cookiename','',[
        'expires' => time() + 1,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'secure' => true,
        'samesite' => 'strict'
        ]);
```

Unfortunately, this workaround seems to suddenly be failing today and that failure *does* seem to be unique to Firefox. (So, yup, perhaps an FF bug?)

Chrome and Vivaldi are still working fine with it. I didn't test on Safari nor Edge as yet.