# How to get rid of browser warning Cookie "CookieName" has been rejected because it is already expired

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-5.0

In FireFox getting Cookie “.AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider” has been rejected because it is already expired. I know I can change the name of the default cookie name “.AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider” and apply settings but so far no luck. Still getting the warning message.

```
            // in .net core 5.0 > startup > configure block

            var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
            };

            app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);

            // in .net core 5.0 > startup > configureservices block

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            });
```

Tried clearing cache, no luck.

Comment: Regarding this issue in Firefox, you can read this post, which may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038173/cannot-remove-a-cookie-firefox-rejecting-cookies-from- the-past